# Space complexity of quantum collision search?

Tags: cryptanalysis, collision-resistance, reference-request, quantum-cryptanalysis

Is there a known way to reduce the space complexity of [quantum collision search](http://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/9705002v1.pdf) (PDF) beyond what is offered by the built-in time-space tradeoff, while keeping the time complexity significantly below what is achieved by the classical Pollard's rho method?

Comment: Related paper [Daniel J. Bernstein. "Cost analysis of hash collisions: Will quantum computers make SHARCS obsolete?" Workshop Record of SHARCS'09: Special-purpose Hardware for Attacking Cryptographic Systems.](http://cr.yp.to/hash/collisioncost-20090823.pdf)