# What are the implications of quantum collision search algorithms like Ambainis for collision-resistant hash functions?

Tags: hash, collision-resistance, post-quantum-cryptography, quantum-cryptanalysis

I just stumbled onto a series of 2017 papers about applying the Ambainis quantum collision-finding algorithm to hash functions. *(disclaimer: I haven't read all of them in full yet)*:

- [Post-quantum security of the sponge construction](https://eprint.iacr.org/2017/771.pdf)
- [Quantum Collision-Finding in Non-Uniform Random Functions](https://eprint.iacr.org/2017/688.pdf)
- [An Efficient Quantum Collision Search Algorithm and Implications on Symmetric Cryptography](https://eprint.iacr.org/2017/847.pdf)

---

From the latter:

> From similar techniques [to Grover's], quantum collision search is known to attain
>   $O(2^{n/3})$ query complexity, compared to the classical $O(2^{n/2})$. ... Our algorithm is the first to propose a time complexity that improves upon $O(2^{n/2})$, in a simple setting with a single processor.

---

**My questions**: can someone who's been following this research discuss:

1. Implications of this for security practitioners ... will we need to *triple* hash lengths instead of doubling them?
2. Is this family of quantum collision-finding attacks only effective against the sponge construction and SHA-3, or does it apply to hash functions more broadly?

---

Related questions that were asked and answered prior to these 2017 papers:

- [2014] [Space complexity of quantum collision search?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/16195/space-complexity-of-quantum-collision-search)
- [2011] [What security do Cryptographic Sponges offer against generic quantum attacks?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/419/what-security-do-cryptographic-sponges-offer-against-generic-quantum-attacks)

Comment: As far as I can tell, there's no evidence that these actually attains asymptotically better than $O(2^{n/2})$ _cost_ in any realistic models of cost (even assuming the unrealistic premise that a qubit and a qubit operation cost the same as a bit and a bit operation), and all the quantum ones actually scale _worse_ in cost than the best classical one, the van Oorschot–Wiener machine.

Comment: Note that if you were already concerned about _classical_ attacks costing up to $2^c$, you needed to use $2c$-bit hashes already; _even if_ the quantum scaling were $O(2^{n/3})$, you would only need $3c/2$-bit hashes, not $3c$-bit hashes.

Comment: Some discussion: https://blog.cr.yp.to/20171017-collisions.html

Comment: I'm missing something about $3c/2$ not $3c$ .. ?

Comment: Sorry, I meant: you need to use $3c$-bit hashes, but that's only $3/2$ the size of the $2c$-bit hashes you needed to thwart classical attacks.

Comment: Good find on the cr.yp.to article. A summary of that would answer both my questions.

Comment: Also the paper you quoted from quotes [the relevant pape](https://cr.yp.to/hash/collisioncost-20090517.pdf)r by Bernstein directly afterwards which essentially says that the $O(2^{n/3})$ complexity / cost is unrealistic.

Answer (score 3):

The *query* complexity, *i.e.* the number of times the machine evaluates the function as a black box, may be $O(2^{n/3})$, but that's not the only cost of an algorithm: the size of the machine and how long you have to run it figure in too.

**So far, there are *no implications* of quantum algorithms for security parameters of collision-resistant hash functions.  Classical algorithms are still the *cheapest* algorithms for generic collision-finding, and would remain so even if Grover-capable quantum computers had the decency to merely exist.**

The original Brassard–Høyer–Tapp algorithm[[1]](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9705002) precomputes $H(x_1), H(x_2), \dots, H(x_{2^{n/3}})$ and stores them in a table $C$; then it applies Grover to find a preimage of 1 under the function $f(y) = [H(y) \in C]$, which reveals a collision in $H$.

Even if the communication costs for table lookup were zero (which seems unrealistic), this costs $O(2^{n/3})$ space, and the algorithm is expected to take $O(2^{n/3})$ oracle evaluations before finding a preimage under $f$ of 1, for a total of $O(2^{n/3})$ evaluations of $H$, and a total area*time *cost* of $O(2^{2n/3})$—far greater than the $O(2^{n/2})$ area*time cost of standard classical algorithms like the van Oorschot and Wiener collision search algorithm based on parallel $\rho$[[2]](http://people.scs.carleton.ca/~paulv/papers/JoC97.pdf).

Variants of the algorithm have been proposed, but so far none of them has beaten the $O(2^{n/2})$ cost of the best classical algorithms in any plausible cost model even if qubit operations are no more expensive than bit operations—and most of them are *much more expensive* in any plausible cost model[[3]](https://cr.yp.to/papers.html#collisioncost).  See [here](https://blog.cr.yp.to/20171017-collisions.html) for an overview of some of the proposed algorithms and of problems in the cost models, and for broader context.

The Ambainis algorithm[[4]](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0311001) takes a slightly different approach of a quantum random walk to find a repetition if there is one among a sequence of $M$ elements in $O(M^{2/3})$ time, which can be converted to an algorithm for finding a collision in an $m$-bit-to-$n$-bit function in $O(2^{m/3})$ queries.  But it also requires maintaining a data structure holding all $O(M^{2/3})$ queries throughout the algorithm.  So the area*time cost for a collision search based on it is $O(2^{2m/3})$, which remains far beyond the $O(2^{n/2})$ cost of classical collision search for any input size $m$ that gives a collision in $n$-bit outputs with nonnegligible probability.  What Czajkowski *et al.* describe[[5]](https://eprint.iacr.org/2017/771) is a generic way to apply it to a sponge with $c$-bit capacity producing an $n$-bit output costing $O(\min\{2^{2c/3}, 2^{2n/3}\})$, which is essentially what you would expect.

And since the query complexity of a generic quantum collision search has a *lower* bound[[6]](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0112086) of $\Omega((2^n/r)^{1/3})$ if $r$ is an upper bound on the number of colliding preimages, unless there are dramatic breakthroughs in *storage* costs it seems unlikely that this situation will change any time soon.

Comment: So the complexity for breaking a hash function's collision resistance is greater than $O(n^{1/3})$? $O(n^{1/3})$ would mean that the bit-equivalent collision resistance of a hash function is at most $n/3$ instead of $n/2$, right? If so, is it possible that there exists a quantum algorithm faster than BHT that could reduce it further to like $n/4$?